# Input on dictionnary with a counter

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new at Python, and i need your help for this.
I have a user input like :

```
5 72 245 62
```

And i need to split this integers into a dictionary like this :

```
{1=5;2=72;3=245;4=62}
```

I tried something like :

```
sequence = dict(x ,input().split())
```

Where `x` is incrementing counter.

Comment: Please, format input and dictionary as the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your desired end result is a Python dictionary, then I think you're pretty close.

You can actually use a python builtin to achieve this called `enumerate`:

```
>>> values = input().split()
1 2 3 4
>>> values
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> 
>>> sequence = dict(enumerate(values))
>>> sequence
{0: '1', 1: '2', 2: '3', 3: '4'}
```

`enumerate` just goes through any iterable (such as a list of strings) and outputs the index of each item and the item itself in a tuple:

```
>>> for x in enumerate(values):
...   print(x)
... 
(0, '1')
(1, '2')
(2, '3')
(3, '4')
```

You can then call `dict` on an iterable of `tuples` (which is what `enumerate` produces) in order to turn them into a dictionary.

Of course, `enumerate`, like most things is zero-indexed, so you can also pass in a **starting** number if you would like to start a 1:

```
>>> sequence = dict(enumerate(values, 1))
>>> sequence
{1: '1', 2: '2', 3: '3', 4: '4'}
```

---

**The problem with what you have**

Let's say, as above, we have a list of strings. In order to match up numbers with each string in the list, we need something like the following:

```
>>> dict([(1, '1'), (2, '2')...])
```

Notice that I am passing *one* *argument* to `dict`: a list of tuples where each item in the list looks like `(1, '1')` and I have one container holding *all* of them.

Your attempt was the following:

```
>>> sequence = dict(x ,input().split())
```

This is interpreted probably something like (guessing on the `x`):

```
>>> dict(1, ['1', '2', '3'])
```

Which produces the following Traceback:

```
>>> dict(1, [1, 2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

You are passing two arguments to `dict`, not one, which is what it expects.

It expects some kind of container with a bunch of things in it where the first element of each thing is mapped to the second element, such as the following:

```
>>> [(1, '1'), (2, '2')]
```

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer, i've learned a lot of things. Your solution does perfectly work. However, i just realized that i need to sort this dictionary on values (but keys need to stay with their values). And apparently, dictionary can't be sorted.

Comment: This is true: dictionaries cannot be sorted, but this is good because it makes them efficient containers. If you need sorted data, you can either use a list (such as the list of tuples), or you can sort the data add it to an `OrderedDict`.